# Distribuir vistas MVC Java

Tags: java, mvc, jsp

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de CRUD de una tabla Empleados con Java y MySQL, con el patrón de diseño MVC en el IDE Eclipse, he creado dos vistas, una para enlistar la consulta de empleados y otra con el formulario para crear el empleado, también he creado el respectivo Controlador y Modelo de Empleado.

Esta es mi estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las vistas que he creado, se repite el código del head y footer. Pregunta: ¿existe una forma de fragmentar las vistas, es decir, en un archivo crear el head, en otro archivo iría el body correspondiente y en el otro archivo iría el footer, y en el momento dado de invocar la vista, que se haga el llamado de los tres archivos? De esta manera solo se crearía una vez el código del head y del footer.

He aquí el código de la vista del formulario para crear empleado

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, Controller.*, Model.*" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Listado de Empleados</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <!-- Fonts and icons -->
    <script src="./assets/js/plugin/webfont/webfont.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        WebFont.load({
            google: {"families":["Lato:300,400,700,900"]},
            custom: {"families":["Flaticon", "Font Awesome 5 Solid", "Font Awesome 5 Regular", "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "simple-line-icons"], urls: ['./assets/css/fonts.min.css']},
            active: function() {
                sessionStorage.fonts = true;
            }
        });
    </script>

    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/atlantis.min.css">

    <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/demo.css">

    <!--DataTable-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

    <!--DataTable-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body class="body">

<div class="container-fluid">


<div class="page-inner">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h4 class="page-title">Empleados</h4>
        <ul class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="nav-home">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="flaticon-home"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="separator">
                <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Empleados</a>
            </li>
            <li class="separator">
                <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Contratar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">Crear Empleado</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="#" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Numero de identificacion</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="emp_cdl" placeholder="Cédula">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Nombres</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_nmbr" placeholder="Nombres">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Apellidos</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_aplld" placeholder="Apellidos">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Dirección</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_drccn" placeholder="Dirección">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Teléfono</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="emp_tlfn" placeholder="Teléfono">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Correo electrónico</label>
                            <input type="mail" class="form-control" name="emp_crr" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                        </div> 

                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Cargo</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="emp_crg">
                                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                <c:forEach var="tempCargo" items="${ListaCargos}">
                                <option value="${tempCargo.crg_id}">${tempCargo.crg_dscrpcn}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="emp_fncmnt">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Fecha Ingreso</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="emp_fingrs">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Nombre Contacto Emergencia</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_nmbrcntctmrgnc" placeholder="Contacto Emergencia">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Teléfono Contacto Emergencia</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="emp_tlfncntctmrgnc">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Parentesco Contacto Emergencia</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_prntzccntctmrgnc">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Nivel Académico</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_nvlcdmc" placeholder="Nivel Académico">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Libreta Militar</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_lbrtmltr" placeholder="Libreta Militar">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Licencia Conducción</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_lcnccndccn" placeholder="Licencia Conducción">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Fecha Expedición Documento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="emp_fxpdc">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Lugar Expedición Documento</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_lgrxpdcn" placeholder="Lugar Expedición Documento">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Nombre Centro Medico</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="emp_cmedico">
                                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                <c:forEach var="tempCentroMedico" items="${ListaCentrosMedico}">
                                <option value="${tempCentroMedico.ctm_id}">${tempCentroMedico.ctm_nmbr}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Ciudad Empleado</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad Empleado">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>EPS</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="emp_eps">
                                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                <c:forEach var="tempEps" items="${ListaEps}">
                                <option value="${tempEps.eps_id}">${tempEps.eps_nmbr}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Panadería</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="emp_pndr">
                                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                <c:forEach var="tempPan" items="${ListaPanaderias}">
                                <option value="${tempPan.pnd_id}">${tempPan.pnd_nmbr} </option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Sueldo</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="emp_sueldo" placeholder="Sueldo">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">Salir</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar Empleado</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#empleado').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
            [ '10 Filas', '25 Filas', '50 Filas','100 Filas', 'Mostrar Todos' ]
            ],
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pageLength',
                text: 'Filtrar # Filas'
            },
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: 'Copiar al Portapapeles'
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                text: 'Exportar CSV'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Exportar Excel'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                text: 'Exportar Pdf'
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Imprimir Tabla'
            }
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>



<script src="./assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Scrollbar -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>


<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/chart.js/chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Sparkline -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart Circle -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/chart-circle/circles.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Notify -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Vector Maps -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>

<!-- Sweet Alert -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<!-- Atlantis JS -->
<script src="./assets/js/atlantis.min.js"></script>

<!-- Atlantis DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! 
<script src="./assets/js/setting-demo.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/demo.js"></script>-->
<script src="./assets/js/core/global.js"></script>
<script>
    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-1',
        radius:45,
        value:60,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 5,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#FF9E27'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-2',
        radius:45,
        value:70,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 36,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#2BB930'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-3',
        radius:45,
        value:40,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 12,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#F25961'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    var totalIncomeChart = document.getElementById('totalIncomeChart').getContext('2d');

    var mytotalIncomeChart = new Chart(totalIncomeChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S", "M", "T"],
            datasets : [{
                label: "Total Income",
                backgroundColor: '#ff9e27',
                borderColor: 'rgb(23, 125, 255)',
                data: [6, 4, 9, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 10],
            }],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                            display: false //this will remove only the label
                        },
                        gridLines : {
                            drawBorder: false,
                            display : false
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes : [ {
                        gridLines : {
                            drawBorder: false,
                            display : false
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
        });

    $('#lineChart').sparkline([105,103,123,100,95,105,115], {
        type: 'line',
        height: '70',
        width: '100%',
        lineWidth: '2',
        lineColor: '#ffa534',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 165, 52, .14)'
    });
</script>



<!--DataTable-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Aquí el código de la vista de enlistar empleados

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, Controller.*, Model.*" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Listado de Empleados</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <!-- Fonts and icons -->
    <script src="./assets/js/plugin/webfont/webfont.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        WebFont.load({
            google: {"families":["Lato:300,400,700,900"]},
            custom: {"families":["Flaticon", "Font Awesome 5 Solid", "Font Awesome 5 Regular", "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "simple-line-icons"], urls: ['./assets/css/fonts.min.css']},
            active: function() {
                sessionStorage.fonts = true;
            }
        });
    </script>

    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/atlantis.min.css">

    <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/demo.css">

    <!--DataTable-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

    <!--DataTable-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body class="body">

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="page-inner">

    <div class="page-header">
        
        <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h4 class="page-title"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Empleados</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Nuevo Empleado" onclick="window.location.href='Controller_Empleado?instruccion=contratar'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <ul class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="nav-home">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="flaticon-home"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="separator">
                <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Empleados</a>
            </li>
            <li class="separator">
                <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Consultar Empleados</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>



    <table id="empleado" class="display table" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
        
            <tr class="thead-light">
                <th>Nombres y Apellidos</th>
                <th>Cédula</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
                <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                <th>Fecha Retiro</th>
                <th>Panadería</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody" id="tbodyConsultarProveedor">
             
            <c:forEach var="tempEmp" items="${ListaEmpleados}">
            
                <c:url var="linkTemp" value="Controller_Empleado">
                    <c:param name="instruccion" value="cargar"></c:param>
                    <c:param name="CEmpleado" value="${tempEmp.emp_cdl}"></c:param>
                </c:url>
                
                <c:url var="linkTempDelete" value="Controller_Empleado">
                    <c:param name="instruccion" value="eliminar"></c:param>
                    <c:param name="CEmpleado" value="${tempEmp.emp_cdl}"></c:param>
                </c:url>
                
                <tr >   
                    <td> ${tempEmp.emp_nmbr} ${tempEmp.emp_aplld} </td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_cdl }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_tlfn }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_drccn }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_ciudad }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_crg }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_fingrs }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_frtr }</td>
                    <td>${tempEmp.emp_pndr }</td>
                    <td><a href="${linkTemp}">Actualizar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="${linkTempDelete}">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot class="bg-primary text-white">
            <tr class="thead-light">
                <th>Nombres y Apellidos</th>
                <th>Cédula</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
                <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                <th>Fecha Retiro</th>
                <th>Panadería</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>    
    </table>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#empleado').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
            [ '10 Filas', '25 Filas', '50 Filas','100 Filas', 'Mostrar Todos' ]
            ],
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pageLength',
                text: 'Filtrar # Filas'
            },
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: 'Copiar al Portapapeles'
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                text: 'Exportar CSV'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Exportar Excel'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                text: 'Exportar Pdf'
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Imprimir Tabla'
            }
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>



<script src="./assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Scrollbar -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>


<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/chart.js/chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Sparkline -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart Circle -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/chart-circle/circles.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Notify -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Vector Maps -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>

<!-- Sweet Alert -->
<script src="./assets/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<!-- Atlantis JS -->
<script src="./assets/js/atlantis.min.js"></script>

<!-- Atlantis DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! 
<script src="./assets/js/setting-demo.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/demo.js"></script>-->
<script src="./assets/js/core/global.js"></script>
<script>
    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-1',
        radius:45,
        value:60,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 5,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#FF9E27'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-2',
        radius:45,
        value:70,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 36,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#2BB930'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    Circles.create({
        id:'circles-3',
        radius:45,
        value:40,
        maxValue:100,
        width:7,
        text: 12,
        colors:['#f1f1f1', '#F25961'],
        duration:400,
        wrpClass:'circles-wrp',
        textClass:'circles-text',
        styleWrapper:true,
        styleText:true
    })

    var totalIncomeChart = document.getElementById('totalIncomeChart').getContext('2d');

    var mytotalIncomeChart = new Chart(totalIncomeChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S", "M", "T"],
            datasets : [{
                label: "Total Income",
                backgroundColor: '#ff9e27',
                borderColor: 'rgb(23, 125, 255)',
                data: [6, 4, 9, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 10],
            }],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                            display: false //this will remove only the label
                        },
                        gridLines : {
                            drawBorder: false,
                            display : false
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes : [ {
                        gridLines : {
                            drawBorder: false,
                            display : false
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
        });

    $('#lineChart').sparkline([105,103,123,100,95,105,115], {
        type: 'line',
        height: '70',
        width: '100%',
        lineWidth: '2',
        lineColor: '#ffa534',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 165, 52, .14)'
    });
</script>



<!--DataTable-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w50Ue.png
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Te refieres a *include* (hay dos versiones, como directiva y como tag)? Puedes ver más detalles [en esta pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in)

Comment: En el controlador tengo esta estructura:  private void contratar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  List<Cargo> cargos=new ArrayList<>();
  try{
   cargos=modelCargo.getCargos();
   //Agregar lista de empleados al request
   request.setAttribute("ListaCargos", cargos);
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  
  
  RequestDispatcher miDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("view/empleado/insertar_empleado.jsp");
  miDispatcher.forward(request, response);



 }

Comment: Estoy mostrando el contenido de estas vistas en un index que tiene la etiqueta iframe:   <iframe name="myFrame" style="height:100%; width:100%;Border:0"> </iframe> El llamado para que el contenido se muestre en ese espacio lo hago así: <a href="Controller_Empleado?instruccion=contratar" target="myFrame"><span class="sub-item">Contratar</span></a>